# Contrast Codes for Regression

Tags: regression, categorical-data

I'm confused about which predictor gets the "-1" or the "1" when using **contrast codes** and not dummy codes for recoding variables. For example, I prepared the following contrast codes by following my textbook but I don't understand *why* I'm doing it this way:

Y variable: time spent at job
X variable: type of assessment method: (1) interview, I (2) competency, C (3) written, W

Q. The researcher wants to know if written (W) result in different time spent at a job from applicants assessed with interviews (I) or competency (C). She also wants to determine if there is a difference in time spent at job between interview (I) and competency (C).

My answer (based on textbook):

1. New variable 1: I --> +1, C --> +1, W --> -2
2. New variable 2: I --> +1, C --> -1, W --> 0

(Because I am comparing comparing the written to interviews **or** competency and I am also comparing interviews **and** competency. In addition, this would make my new variables orthogonal since they all add up to 0). Is this the proper way to think about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dummy Coding for Regression?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244456/dummy-coding-for-regression)

Comment: If you do not understand the answers you got last time then add comments there, not ask the same question again.

Comment: This question is about contrast coding and the other one is about dummy coding so I thought I had to separate it. Apologies for the confusion. I'll refrain from doing so in future!

Comment: The linked thread is about reference level coding, whereas this is about effect (?) coding (I think). At any rate, these don't seem to be duplicates.

Comment: Sunmi, you might want also to read this [answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/221868/3277) which explains how your hypothesis (which groups to compare) guides you to create contrast coefficients which in turn define contrast codes to use in regression.