# OLS regression model time series

Tags: regression, least-squares

Apologize in advance for there being not a lot of wisdom here..

But If I am creating a multiple linear regression model with time series data, (more specifically using day-of-week dummy variables for my independent variables) I would need to build one of my day-of-week variables into the intercept of the model, right?

For example,

if the date = Monday, the value for this variable/column in the dataset would be 1 else 0.
if the date = Tuesday, the value for this variable/column in the dataset would be 1 else 0..
if the date = Wednesday, the value for this variable/column in the dataset would be 1 else 0...

And so on for all days of the week. If this is true could someone help explain the theory behind why one independent variable needs to be built into the intercept? I cant remember where I learned this from..

Comment: You don’t have to build it into the intercept, but if you don’t, leave out an intercept term or your model matrix will not have full rank. You may be interested in a post of mine: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/439818/247274

Comment: Can you explain that more in more detail? It sort of makes sense...

Comment: I’ve included a link to a post of mine that goes through this.

Comment: Thank you......