# how to interpret classes dependence that are not the reference class in a linear model

Tags: r, regression, categorical-encoding

If we run the three following codes:

```
n <- 250
df <- rbind(
  data.frame(cat=1, x=rnorm(n, 0), y=rnorm(n, 1)),
  data.frame(cat=2, x=rnorm(n, 0), y=rnorm(n, 0)),
  data.frame(cat=3, x=rnorm(n, 0), y=rnorm(n, 0))
)
df$cat <- as.factor(df$cat)
df$cat <- relevel(df$cat, ref = "1")

summary(lm(y ~ cat, df))
```

It will say here that intercept, cat2 and cat3 are statistically significant in trying to predict y. But doesn't indicate that cat=2 and cat=3 are actually redundant.

```
n <- 250
df <- rbind(
  data.frame(cat=1, x=rnorm(n, 0), y=rnorm(n, 1)),
  data.frame(cat=2, x=rnorm(n, 0), y=rnorm(n, 0)),
  data.frame(cat=3, x=rnorm(n, 0), y=rnorm(n, 0))
)
df$cat <- as.factor(df$cat)
df$cat <- relevel(df$cat, ref = "2")

summary(lm(y ~ cat, df))
```

Here only cat1 is significant.

```
n <- 250
df <- rbind(
  data.frame(cat=1, x=rnorm(n, 0), y=rnorm(n, 1)),
  data.frame(cat=2, x=rnorm(n, 0), y=rnorm(n, 0)),
  data.frame(cat=3, x=rnorm(n, 0), y=rnorm(n, 0))
)
df$cat <- as.factor(df$cat)
df$cat <- relevel(df$cat, ref = "3")

summary(lm(y ~ cat, df))
```

Same here (which makes sense).

**Do we have to run several times the linear model to see that cat2 and cat3 don't need to be both used to predict y?**
What if only the intercept is significant, what does that mean? I'm not able to reproduce a case where that happens and it happens in my dataset. Does that mean we don't need any of the 3 categorical variables to predict y? Why wouldn't be all p values not significant in that case?

Comment: The inconsistencies between the code and your text makes it difficult to determine what your model really is.  Do you have one set of data or multiple sets? Do you have *a single* categorical variable with three levels or do you contemplate having *three* different (binary?) categorical variables?  It sure looks like the first, but then you have no choice: either you include the variable or you don't.

Comment: I have a single categorical variable with three levels. But I guess what I'm trying to say is are two of these levels redundant to predict y?

Comment: That question comes down to whether you can predict $y$ equally well by collapsing those two levels into a single category (along with a second category for the third level, of course: if you collapsed them all into one value it wouldn't vary and thereby would useless for prediction).  If this is something you had in mind before analyzing the data, you can test this hypothesis; but otherwise, you might be reading too much into the results (HARKing is a standard but pejorative term for that approach) and would be better off keeping things as is.

Comment: Ok fair enough, just read about HARKing and it makes sense.

Comment: Little question though, if I do have incercept significant and the rest not significant, how should I interpret the analysis?

Comment: See also  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285210/what-to-do-in-a-multinomial-logistic-regression-when-all-levels-of-dv-are-of-int/544656#544656

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a frequent confusion arising from the way that coefficient estimates and p-values are typically displayed for multi-level categorical predictors. With this default treatment coding, the intercept is the outcome at the reference level and the coefficients are the *differences* from that outcome associated with the other levels.

The choice of reference level matters in terms of display, but not for the fundamental model. If you change the reference level, [both the intercept and the other coefficient estimates will change](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/439815/28500).

In this particular case you can get a clearer display if you omit the intercept. (I set the seed to 2552 before continuing with your code to generate df, and kept the reference level at "1".)

```
lm2 <- lm(y ~ -1 + cat, df)
```

Instead of focusing on the individual coefficients and p-values, examine the overall significance of the categorical predictor. With these data, standard `anova()` is a good choice (particularly as this is just a balanced ANOVA in `lm` form). The predictor is highly significant, as intended.

```
anova(lm2)
# Analysis of Variance Table
# 
# Response: y
#            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
# cat         3 269.47  89.824  86.183 < 2.2e-16
# Residuals 747 778.56   1.042
```

With the intercept omitted, each of the levels is shown with its own mean value and the significance of its difference from 0.

```
summary(lm2)

## some output lines omitted

# Coefficients:
#      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# cat1  1.03630    0.06457  16.050   <2e-16
# cat2 -0.05519    0.06457  -0.855    0.393    
# cat3  0.03040    0.06457   0.471    0.638
```

That trick, however, only works with a single categorical predictor.

In general with treatment coding, the intercept represents a situation when all categorical predictors are at their reference levels and continuous predictors are at 0. So the "significance" of the intercept is just whether the outcome is significantly different from 0 *for that particular choice of reference levels and centering of continuous predictors*. In many circumstances that "significance" isn't very useful on its own.

Similarly the "significance" of a coefficient for a non-reference level is whether its *difference* from the outcome at the reference level can be distinguished from 0.  So that also depends on the choice of reference level.

Nevertheless, outcome predictions for any level of a categorical predictor will be the same regardless of reference-level or predictor-centering choices. It's often wise just to ignore the coefficient p-values in this situation and look directly at predictions or differences between predictions.

The [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) provides a general way to display more useful model summaries of that type. It works with the original model to display particular estimates or comparisons of interest.

```
library(emmeans)
emmeans(lm2,pairwise~cat)
# $emmeans
#  cat  emmean     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
#  1    1.0363 0.0646 747   0.9095   1.1631
#  2   -0.0552 0.0646 747  -0.1819   0.0716
#  3    0.0304 0.0646 747  -0.0964   0.1572
# 
# Confidence level used: 0.95 
# 
# $contrasts
#  contrast estimate     SE  df t.ratio p.value
#  1 - 2      1.0915 0.0913 747  11.953  <.0001
#  1 - 3      1.0059 0.0913 747  11.016  <.0001
#  2 - 3     -0.0856 0.0913 747  -0.937  0.6168
# 
# P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 
#
```

The `$emmeans` are the outcome estimates for each level, the `$contrasts` are the estimates of differences between each pair of predictor levels, with a p-value correction for multiple comparisons. You would get the same results if you used modeled the same data while including the intercept, or with any other choice of reference level.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Helped me a ton. If instead of doing `y ~ cat` I want to do the same but the other way around `cat ~ y` (predicting cat with y instead of predicting y with cat), I would have to use a multinomial classification model. I did so with `multinom` from `nnet`. I found the emmeans package page (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html#N) and it says `multinom` is supported but I'm not sure I understand what they mean by `trt`. Do you have any idea? My code is currently `emmeans(multinom(cat~ y, data = df), ~ cat)` and it returns `NULL`

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows `emmeans()` uses a "reference grid" for a model, the set of predictor-value combinations over which it makes estimates and contrasts. It uses all combinations of levels of categorical predictors, but it only uses the mean of a continuous predictor like `y` unless you first define a grid yourself with the `ref_grid()` function. The `trt` in the page you linked is when, in addition to other predictors, there are treatments (`trt`) for which you want separate breakdowns of outcome. Allow a few hours to study `emmeans`; that will save much time in the long run.