# What algorithms require one-hot encoding?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, categorical-encoding, data-preprocessing

I'm never sure when to use one-hot encoding for *non-ordered* categorical variables and when not to. I use it whenever the algorithm uses a distance metric to compute similarity. Can anyone give a general rule of thumb as to what types of algorithms would require non-ordered categorical features to be one-hot-encoded and which ones wouldn't?

Comment: Are you asking about the need to code categorical data into some type of "contrast variables" or _specifically_ into dummy (one-hot) type?

Comment: This question is somewhat broad, but a simple answer that addresses the nature of OHE can clear up the OP's confusion. The existence of such answers implies this question is answerable. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: @ttnphns honestly I don't know what you mean by contrast variable. I'm only familiar with dummy.

Comment: Cosmos, dummy (=indicator =one-hot) is just one of a number of ways to encode categorical cariables in analyses. Theses ways unitely are called "contrast variables". See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4669/3277 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/221868/3277

Comment: I think the complete list you ask for is going to be hard to produce.

Comment: @mdewey I modified the question to read "general rule of thumb" and "types" of algorithms, instead of specific algorithms. Hopefully this will make the question easier to answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Most** algorithms (linear regression, logistic regression, neural network, support vector machine, etc.) require some sort of the encoding on categorical variables. This is because most algorithms only take numerical values as inputs.

Algorithms that do not require an encoding are **algorithms that can directly deal with joint discrete distributions** such as Markov chain / Naive Bayes / Bayesian network, tree based, etc.

Additional comments:

- One hot encoding is one of the encoding methods. Here is a good resource for categorical variable encoding (not limited to R). [R LIBRARY CONTRAST CODING SYSTEMS FOR CATEGORICAL VARIABLES](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/)
- Even without encoding, distance between data points with discrete variables can be defined, such as [hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) or [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: It is still not clear if one hot encoding is required for MOST ALGORITHMS. You just say that encoding is required. But is it one hot encoding?

Answer (score 7):

> Can anyone give a list of what algorithms would require categorical features to be one-hot-encoded and which ones wouldn't?

AFAIU, it has to do more with the particular *data*, less with the particular *algorithm*. Specifically, it depends on whether there is some meaningful order in the categories or not.

Consider two cases. In the first you have the categories *bad, meh, good*, and in the second you have *apple, orange, pear*. There is a natural order in the first case, because *meh* is probably in between *bad* and *good*, but probably nothing similar happens in *apple, orange, pear*.

If you avoid one-hot encoding for the first case, you're "losing" the information about the order. If you use one-hot encoding for the second case, you're assigning some order to the categories that is not naturally true.

> I do it whenever the algorithm uses a distance metric to compute similarity.

Why? Suppose one of the features is a categorical *bad, meh, good*, and you have three instances, 1, 2, and 3, where they are identical, except that 1 is *bad*, 2 is *meh*, and 3 is good. You probably want to express to the algorithm that 1 is more similar to 2 than it is to 3.

Comment: That's a good answer. I should have clarified the question though to include non-ordered categorical variables as well. In that case, it should always be one hot encoded?

Comment: @cosmos1990 IMHO, as a rule of thumb, for non-ordered categorical data, one-hot encoding is the way to go (as opposed to assignment of numerical values).

Answer (score 2):

No machine learning algorithm *requires*  one hot encoding.  It is  one method for dealing with categorical variables. Dummy variables is another.  Traditionally, dummy variables was the preferred solution. For example, the R function lm() automatically creates dummy variables for categorical data.  If you are using python and scikt-learn then I believe many of it's algos require one-hot encoding of categorical variables. I believe that tensorFlow also requires one-hot encoding.  These are choices of how the variable is encoded.  There is no reason why dummy variables couldn't be used in the code instead.  This all has to deal with the actual code implementation of the algorithm.

As hxd1011 points out the issue of describing the 'distance' between categorical variables is a delicate issue.  In addition to the distances mentioned there is also Jaccard distance.  Some ML methods, particularly SVM's are inappropriate for categorical data and adding categorical variables can/will (either, both, you decide) lead to models with very poor predictive power. Most ensemble models handle categorical data 'as is' and require no pre-processing.