# Dummy coding versus contrasts: which compares treatment with control?

Tags: anova, categorical-encoding, contrasts

I have a data set where I want to compare different treatments with a certain baseline. So I basically have a linear model (ANOVA) like this:

> outcome = b_0 + sum_i(b_i * x_i)

with b_i the fitted parameters and x_i dummy variables or contrasts. Now I have two ways I can code my dummy variables:

**1) default dummy coding**

> for treatment k: x_k = 1, x_i = 0 for i!=k
>
> for baseline: x_i = 0 for all i

in this way, I obtain:

> b_0 = mean(outcome(control))
>
> b_i = mean(outcome(treatment_i)) - mean(outcome(control))

**2) (non-orthogonal) contrasts to explicitly compare treatments with baseline**

> for treatment k: x_k = 1, x_i = 0 for i!=k
>
> for baseline: x_i = -1 for all i

in this way, I obtain:

> b_0 = mean(outcome(all)) = "grand mean"
>
> b_i = mean(outcome(treatment_i)) - "grand mean"

So, although I expected the second coding to be the one that explicitly compares treatments with the baseline (by having a "-1,1" contrast for each treatment) **[*]**, it actually compares treatments with the grand mean, which I don't want.

I see that I will have to use option **1)**, but I am confused by the fact that the contrasts actually don't do what I expect them to do. So what is wrong with my reasoning in option **2)**?

---

**[*]** (*edit to clear things up a bit*): This reasoning was coming from the book "Discovering Statistics Using R" from Andy Field. There, he gave a nice recipe to define "contrasts" using weights:

> - **Rule 1**: Choose sensible comparisons. Remember that you want to compare only two chunks of variation and that if a group is singled
>   out in one comparison, that group should be excluded from any
>   subsequent contrasts.
> - **Rule 2**: Groups coded with positive weights will be compared against groups coded with negative weights. So, assign one chunk of
>   variation positive weights and the opposite chunk negative weights.
> - **Rule 3**: The sum of weights for a comparison should be zero. If you add up the weights for a given contrast the result should be zero.
> - **Rule 4**: If a group is not involved in a comparison, automatically assign it a weight of 0. If we give a group a weight of
>   0 then this eliminates that group from all calculations.
> - **Rule 5**: For a given contrast, the weights assigned to the group(s) in one chunk of variation should be equal to the number of
>   groups in the opposite chunk of variation.

A bit further in the book, he explains that non-orthogonal comparisons can also be done with the same recipe, but by simply disobeying rule 1 in the recipe above.

Comment: What you call "contrasts" is deviation type contrasts. You might want to use simple contrasts if you want b0 to represent grand mean but bi to represent mean_i - mean_ref. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/221868/3277

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am answering my own question here.)

My confusion was a result of the very ill-defined concept of contrasts or contrast matrices. The very nice answer of [@ttnphns](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/3277/ttnphns) [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/221868/144133) could clear everything up for me.

So, apparently the recipe of Andy Field works only for orthogonal contrasts; if you use it to define non-orthogonal contrasts, you won't get what you expect.

### How does the dummy coding work and how to get to the interpretation of b coefficents?

Consider a one-way ANOVA which models an outcome y as function of a factor A with K levels:

```
y ~ A
```

Equivalently, we can consider a regression model with k-1 dummy or contrast variables x_i (as defined in the question):

```
observation n of N: y(n) = b_{0} + b_{1}*x_{1}(n) + ... + b_{k-1} *x_{K-1}(n) + error
```

We can combine all N observations in one matrix description, which we can solve to get the fitted b coefficients:

```
Y = X*b ( + error)
```

with Y a column with N observations, b a column of K fitted parameters (the first one being the offset), and X a "K x N"-matrix, with the first column being 1's (corresponding to the offset). This can be solved to obtain the fitted b parameters:

```
b = (X^T * X)^(-1) * X^T *Y
```

Now we can summarize this description by using the mean (as calculated by the model) for each level:

```
Y_mean = C*b
```

with Y_mean a column for the K observed groups. C is now a "K x K"-matrix; the first column is still a column of 1's. For example, one row for group k:

```
Y_mean(k) = b_{0} + b_{1}*x_{1}(k) + ... + b_{k-1} *x_{K-1}(k)
```

(no more error because this is the mean as fitted by the model)

This matrix C can be called a **"contrast coding matrix"**. It tells you the values of the dummy variables for each level of the factor A. **The last K-1 columns** (the first column is always a column of 1's) **is what you enter in R as the "contrast matrix"**.

Now, this C is invertible, such that we obtain (this corresponds to the calculation of the b coefficients as a function of group means as it done in your book):

```
b = C^(-1) * Y_mean = L * Y_mean
```

This matrix L can be called the **"contrast coefficient matrix"**. It gives you an interpretation of the b coefficients as a function of the group means. This means that **we have to look at this matrix L, and not at the contrast coding matrix, when we want to interpret what our contrasts are doing**.

### So why can you sometimes use the dummy$^1$ variables themselves (matrix C) to interpret the b coefficients?

If your matrix C consists of orthogonal columns, the inverse of this matrix C will have rows that are proportional to the rows of the transpose of this matrix C. Or in other words, the rows of matrix L are proportional to the columns of matrix C if C consists of orthogonal columns. This means that C can also be used to interpret the meaning of the contrast variables, but only if the contrasts are orthogonal.

---

$^1$ I'm using here word "dummy" in wide sense, i.e. any contrast variable type, not just indicator (or one-hot) type.