# Manually give numeric contrast vector for two or more variables (with both deviation and dummy coding) in GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, contrasts

I need to manually define contrast in a GLM model implemented in DESeq2 model which performs differential expression analysis on read count data of genes using GLM.

I would like to examine which genes have significantly higher expression than the grand mean at each level of a categorical variable let’s say condition2. But while I am doing this, I want to control the effect of condition1.

Here is an example how I define design matrix and contrast matrix

```
condition1 <- factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=6))
a <- sample(rep(1:6, each=3))
condition2 <- factor(a, levels=1:6)
mm <- model.matrix(~ condition1 + condition2,
                   contrasts=list(condition1 = contr.treatment,
                                  condition2 = contr.sum))
```

**First question:** does this design matrix and contrast do what I want: control the effect of condition1 while calculates differences between the levels of condition2 and the overall/grand mean of condition2.

Next, I compile an expression data and perform differential expression analysis where I need to give a contrast vector.

```
library(DESeq2)
count_data <- matrix(sample(1:100, 50 * 18, replace=TRUE), ncol=18)
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(count_data, colData=data.frame(condition1, condition2),
                              design=mm)
dds2 <- DESeq(dds)
res <- results(dds2, contrast=c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

**Second question:** in the last line I need to give a contrast vector which means one numeric value for each coefficient. In this design matrix I have 8 coefficients: Intercept, 2 coefficients for condition1 and 5 coefficients for condition2. The two contrast matrices look like:

```
condition1:

  2 3

A 0 0

B 1 0

C 0 1

condition2:

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]

1    1    0    0    0    0

2    0    1    0    0    0

3    0    0    1    0    0

4    0    0    0    1    0

5    0    0    0    0    1

6   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
```

Am I right if I put together the two contrast matrices I can give `0, 1, 0` for the `intercept` and `condition1` and `1, 0, 0, 0, 0` for `condition2`, so `c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)`? Am I right that this contrast and design would give me the difference between `condition2` `level1` and the grand mean of `condition2` while the effect of `condition1` is controlled?

Thank you for your help!

Torda

Comment: Ok, I realized that in the `res <- results(dds2, contrast=c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))` row, the contrast is a coefficient contrast so I can get it from the inverse of the contrast matrix which will result in `c(0, 1, 0, 4/5, -1/5, -1/5, -1/5, -1/5)`. I came to this conlusion by reading [this forum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78354/what-is-a-contrast-matrix/221868#221868).