# How to encode single & combination treatment groups for mixed effects model?

Tags: categorical-encoding

I am preparing a data analysis for a longitudinal study investigating the effects of two treatments (A & B) over time with the following 4 groups:

- Group 1: Control (Saline)
- Group 2: Treatment A
- Group 3: Treatment B
- Group 4: Treatment A + Treatment B (same doses as group 2 & 3)

I am considering the following encoding schemes:

Make Saline, Treatment A, and Treatment B separate binary categorical variables to create a binary treatment vector [I(Saline) I(Tx A) I(Tx B)] (where I(x) is indicator function which equals 1 if x is present & 0 otherwise) with values as follows:

- Group 1 (Control - Saline): [1 0 0]
- Group 2 (Treatment A):      [0 1 0]
- Group 3 (Treatment B):      [0 0 1]
- Group 4 (Treatment A + B):  [0 1 1]

Make Treatment Group a single categorical variable with 4 non-ordered categories:

- Group 1 (Control - Saline) = 1
- Group 2 (Treatment A) = 2
- Group 3 (Treatment B) = 3
- Group 4 (Treatment A + B) = 4

Make Treatment Group a single categorical variable with saline as base category & 3 non-ordered categories:

- Group 1 (Control - Saline) = 0
- Group 2 (Treatment A) = 1
- Group 3 (Treatment B) = 2
- Group 4 (Treatment A + B) = 3

Which encoding method would be the most appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

They are all the same. Well, I'm not completely clear what you mean in your first example, but we will get to that. Basically, you just have to look a the design matrix corresponding to each way of encoding the variable. We can do this easily in R with a simple example:

```
> expand.grid(trt = c("1","2","3","4"), reps = 1:2) %>%  model.matrix(~ trt, .)
  (Intercept) trt2 trt3 trt4
1           1    0    0    0
2           1    1    0    0
3           1    0    1    0
4           1    0    0    1
5           1    0    0    0
6           1    1    0    0
7           1    0    1    0
8           1    0    0    1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$trt
[1] "contr.treatment"

> expand.grid(trt = c("0","1","2","3"), reps = 1:2 )  %>%  model.matrix(~ trt, .)
  (Intercept) trt1 trt2 trt3
1           1    0    0    0
2           1    1    0    0
3           1    0    1    0
4           1    0    0    1
5           1    0    0    0
6           1    1    0    0
7           1    0    1    0
8           1    0    0    1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$trt
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

which as you can see, are the same.  R uses contrast coding by default, we could use, for example helmert coding:

```
expand.grid(trt = c("1","2","3","4"), reps = 1:2 )  %>%  model.matrix(~ trt, . , contrasts = list(trt = "contr.helmert"))
```

or orthogonal polynomials (`contrasts = list(trt = "contr.poly"))` which would result in different design matrices, but for each way the factor `trt` is encoded (`"1","2","3","4"` or `"0","1","2","3"`) they would be the same, resulting in the same model output.

In your first example, it is not clear what you mean. The way you have written [1 0 0], [0 1 0],[0 0 1] and [0 1 1] makes it seem like you might be thinking of setting your own contrasts, in which cases  this question and answer will tell you all about that:
[What is a contrast matrix?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78354/what-is-a-contrast-matrix)
. On the other hand if those are just binary numbers then they evaluate to 4, 2, 1 and 3 respectively, and if you coded those as levels `("4", "2", "1" "3")` then again you would obtain she same design matrix and thus the same model. You could even code them as `("1 0 0", "0 1 0", "0 0 1", "0 1 1")` and yet again it would be the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, and if not please let us know why.