# How do I interpret a regression model when there are impossible additive effects?

Tags: regression, self-study, interpretation, regression-coefficients, categorical-encoding

Let's say I have a model of count data as a function of the month of the year along with an additive effect of season (factor with 2 levels Wet and Dry which correspond to Jan - June and July to Dec respectively).

```
count ~ month + season
```

My regression will give some main effect estimates for the two parameters. Let's say I have a positive effect of wet season. **How do I interpret this when the effect is on months that are not in the wet season?**

Comment: You’ll never have a December in the wet season, right?

Comment: If `season` is just defined in terms of `month`, then there doesn't seem much point in having both in the same model. `month` alone will capture the season effect + more fine-grained variation.

Comment: @Dave, that's right. So I guess in the model matrix I'd have zeroes for wet season beside the column for the month variable.

Answer (score 2):

Turning my comment into an answer:

If `season` is just defined in terms of `month` and consists of the same set of `month`s each year, there isn't much point in having both in the same model because of the covariance between the two. `month` alone will capture the `season` effect as well as more fine-grained variation. This might be less of a problem if the dry/rainy seasons occurred in different months each year, but in general this isn't likely to work well.

Now to restate your bolded question: "How do I interpret the positive effect of a wet season when the effect is on months that are not in the wet season?"

Even ignoring the model problems I discussed earlier, the question doesn't really make sense. The parameter value for `season` distinguishes between dry and wet seasons. Assuming 'dry' is your reference category, then the `season` parameter value applies only to 'wet' periods (and vice versa). There's no effect of wet season applied to months not in the wet season. The question [What is a contrast matrix?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78354/what-is-a-contrast-matrix) might help make this clearer, and I also suggest looking up 'dummy coding' on this site.