# Custom contrasts with lmer in R for a 3x2 with 2 random factors

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

I would like to test with `lmer` the effect of condition (`cond`: A, B, C) x time (`time`: T1, T2) on some ratings (`rating`) with two random factors: participant (`id`) and target (`target`).

My data looks like this:

```
> X
   time cond  target id rating
1    T1    A target1 s1      4
2    T1    A target1 s2      1
3    T1    B target2 s1      3
4    T1    B target2 s2      6
5    T1    C target3 s1      6
6    T1    C target3 s2      5
7    T2    A target4 s1      2
8    T2    A target4 s2      4
9    T2    A target5 s1      0
10   T2    A target5 s2      4
11   T2    B target6 s1      0
12   T2    B target6 s2      5
13   T2    B target7 s1      4
14   T2    B target7 s2      4
15   T2    C target8 s1      2
16   T2    C target8 s2      3
17   T2    C target9 s1      6
18   T2    C target9 s2      0
```

Please note that in the real dataset there are 70 participants (`id`), they all rated once each target; and there are 22 `target` per `cond` when `time==T2` but *only 1* `target` when `time==T1`.

Based on [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168650/how-to-set-custom-contrasts-with-lmer-in-r) post, this is what I have done so far :

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

# Generate data
X <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("T1", "T2"), class = "factor"), cond = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), target = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("target1", "target2", "target3", "target4", "target5", "target6", "target7", "target8", "target9"), class = "factor"), id = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("s1", "s2"), class = "factor"), rating = c(4L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))

# Contrast coding
X$cond <- factor(X$cond)
X$time <- factor(X$time)
contrasts(X$cond) <- cbind(AvsBC  = c(1,  -0.5, -0.5), # A  vs. (B + C)/2
                           BvsC   = c(0,     1,   -1)) # B  vs. C
contrasts(X$time) <- cbind(T1vsT2 = c(+1, -1))         # T1 vs. T2

# Mixed model
mdl <- lmer(rating ~ cond * time + (1|id) + (1|target), data = X)
summary(mdl)
```

My questions are:

- Does it makes even sense to test a model for which the random factor `target` is "truly" random only when `time==T2`?
- If so, is the formula specified in `lmer` correct?

Comment: Is there anything in the model output that you find problematic, or are you just double-checking?

Comment: I am just double-checking and want to make sure this model makes sense (see point 1). The output seems to be just fine, there is at least no errors and coefficients seems to be correct.

Comment: I think it's OK.

Comment: There is no `contrast` function in base R. Why did you remove the `ginv` part?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Both methods produce the same results. I just find `contrasts` a bit less cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le me try to answer your questions.

- It appears that `target` is not a random factor at all. Ask yourself: Are the targets really drawn independently from a population of targets? If `target` is indeed a *real* random factor in your *actual* dataset, you can treat it in the way you did. You estimate a random intercept only.
- The specified contrasts are correct for the intended comparisons. Furthermore, the model formula including the interaction between both independent variables and two random intercepts appears to be valid.

Comment: `target`, at least in theory, is independently drawn from a population of targets