# Multiple regression with categorical and numeric predictors

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I am relatively new to R, and I am trying to fit a model to data that consists of a categorical column and a numeric (integer) column. The dependent variable is a continuous number.

The data has the following format:

predCateg, predIntNum, ResponseVar

The data looks something like this:

```
ranking, age_in_years, wealth_indicator
category_A, 99, 1234.56
category_A, 21, 12.34
category_A, 42, 234.56
....
category_N, 105, 77.27
```

How would I model this (presumably, using a GLM), in R?

[[Edit]]

It has just occurred to me (after analysing the data more thoroughly), that the categorical independent variable is in fact ordered. I have therefore modified the answer provided earlier as follows:

```
> fit2 <- glm(wealth_indicator ~ ordered(ranking) + age_in_years, data=amort2)
> 
> fit2

Call:  glm(formula = wealth_indicator ~ ordered(ranking) + age_in_years, 
    data = amort2)

Coefficients:
      (Intercept)  ordered(ranking).L  ordered(ranking).Q  ordered(ranking).C      age_in_years  
        0.0578500         -0.0055454         -0.0013000          0.0007603          0.0036818  

Degrees of Freedom: 39 Total (i.e. Null);  35 Residual
Null Deviance:      0.004924 
Residual Deviance: 0.00012      AIC: -383.2
> 
> fit3 <- glm(wealth_indicator ~ ordered(ranking) + age_in_years + ordered(ranking)*age_in_years, data=amort2)
> fit3

Call:  glm(formula = wealth_indicator ~ ordered(ranking) + age_in_years + 
    ordered(ranking) * age_in_years, data = amort2)

Coefficients:
                    (Intercept)                ordered(ranking).L                ordered(ranking).Q  
                      0.0578500                       -0.0018932                       -0.0039667  
              ordered(ranking).C                    age_in_years  ordered(ranking).L:age_in_years  
                      0.0021019                        0.0036818                       -0.0006640  
ordered(ranking).Q:age_in_years  ordered(ranking).C:age_in_years  
                      0.0004848                       -0.0002439  

Degrees of Freedom: 39 Total (i.e. Null);  32 Residual
Null Deviance:      0.004924 
Residual Deviance: 5.931e-05    AIC: -405.4
```

I am a bit confused by what `ordered(ranking).C`, `ordered(ranking).Q` and `ordered(ranking).L` mean in the output, and would appreciate some help in understanding this output, and how to use it to predict the response variable.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
fit <- glm(wealth_indicator ~ 
           factor(ranking) + age_in_years + factor(ranking) * age_in_years)
```

The `factor()` command will make sure that R knows that your variable is categorical. This is especially useful if your categories are indicated by integers, otherwise glm will interpret the variable as continuous.

The `factor(ranking) * age_in_years` term lets R know that you want to include the interaction term.

Comment: why `factor(ranking)` and not `as.factor(ranking)` ?

Comment: I habitually use `factor(x)` so that I can include the `levels` argument if I wish. You could also use `as.factor(x)` if you wish, and it may in fact be faster, but I would think you'd need quite a large dataset for the speed of these functions to matter.

Comment: @PSchnell +1 for a concise answer and a good explanation. One thing however, is that I have realized that the factor is ordered. I modified the formula you provided slightly, to reflect the fact this (please see my edited question). However, I am not sure I understand the model output (specifically `ordered(ranking).C`, `ordered(ranking).Q` and `ordered(ranking).L` - what do they mean, and how do I use that to predict the response variable?) - any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `.L`, `.Q`, and `.C` are, respectively, the coefficients for the ordered factor coded with linear, quadratic, and cubic contrasts. The command `contr.poly(4)` will show you the contrast matrix for an ordered factor with 4 levels (3 degrees of freedom, which is why you get up to a third order polynomial). `contr.poly(4)[2, '.L']` will tell you what to plug in for the second ordered level in the linear term. Be aware that this assumes that it makes sense to consider the levels as equally spaced. If it doesn't, code your own contrast matrix.

Comment: According to http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm#ORTHOGONAL, in R, when a continuous variable is modeled in response to an ordered factor variable, the default contrast applied is orthogonal polynomial coding https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat502/node/203.  http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/206345/90600 has some rather extensive explanation.  http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/207128/90600 goes even deeper.

Comment: Is it different `ordered(ranking)` comparing `factor(ranking)`?

Answer (score 2):

I recently answered [Continuous dependent variable with ordinal independent variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/33413/32036), recommending the `ordSmooth` function in the `ordPens` package. This uses penalized regression to smooth dummy coefficients across levels of an ordinal variable so that they don't vary too greatly from one level to the next. E.g., you probably wouldn't want `category_A`'s coefficient to be much more different from `category_B` than from `category_N`. You'd probably want coefficients to rise or fall monotonically, or at least change gradually across ranks. My answer to the linked question lists references for further info.

`ordSmooth` can also accommodate continuous (and nominal) variables; in your case, code could be:

```
SmoothFit=with(amort2,
ordSmooth(as.numeric(ordered(ranking)),wealth_indicator,z=age_in_years,lambda=.001))
```

`ordSmooth` requires numeric input for ordinal data, hence the `as.numeric(ordered())` reformatting. `z` is for a numeric vector/matrix/`data.frame` of continuous predictors. `lambda` is the smoothing coefficient – larger values will push your coefficients closer to zero. Might be wise to start small here. Printing `SmoothFit` will give you coefficients and fitted values, but I'm afraid it leaves the rest to you.

In your method, the `ordered(ranking).C`/`.Q`/`.L` coefficients appear to be labeled as cubic, quadratic, and linear, respectively. If you try `glm(rnorm(10)~ordered(rep(1:5,2)))`, you'll get a coefficient for `ordered(rep(1:5, 2))^4` as well. I'm not really sure why these are denoted with exponents; I don't think it's modeling these as polynomial terms, because the coefficients are different for `glm(y~x+I(x^2)+I(x^3)+I(x^4))` and scaled variants of this. They should be basic [dummy codes](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/dummy.htm).