# Issues setting up model matrix in R

Tags: r, regression, modeling

I am having difficulty setting up this model matrix. I have been looking through some tutorials and questions online but I can't seem to find the answer to my problem. I am at the point where I have decided I probably have no idea what I am doing. Here is my sample table:

```
structure(list(condition = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Ctrl", "Drug1", 
"Drug1_Drug2"), class = "factor"), genotype = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("KO", 
"WT"), class = "factor"), replicate = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)), .Names = c("condition", "genotype", 
"replicate"), row.names = c("Drug1_WT1", "Drug1_WT2", "Drug1_WT3", 
"Drug1_KO1", "Drug1_Drug2_WT1", "Drug1_Drug2_WT2", "Drug1_Drug2_WT3", 
"Drug1_Drug2_KO1", "Drug1_Drug2_KO2", "Drug1_Drug2_KO3", "Ctrl_WT1", 
"Ctrl_WT2", "Ctrl_WT3", "Ctrl_KO1", "Ctrl_KO2", "Ctrl_KO3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Which looks like this when formatted:

```
                  condition genotype replicate
Drug1_WT1             Drug1       WT         1
Drug1_WT2             Drug1       WT         2
Drug1_WT3             Drug1       WT         3
Drug1_KO1             Drug1       KO         1
Drug1_Drug2_WT1 Drug1_Drug2       WT         1
Drug1_Drug2_WT2 Drug1_Drug2       WT         2
Drug1_Drug2_WT3 Drug1_Drug2       WT         3
Drug1_Drug2_KO1 Drug1_Drug2       KO         1
Drug1_Drug2_KO2 Drug1_Drug2       KO         2
Drug1_Drug2_KO3 Drug1_Drug2       KO         3
Ctrl_WT1               Ctrl       WT         1
Ctrl_WT2               Ctrl       WT         2
Ctrl_WT3               Ctrl       WT         3
Ctrl_KO1               Ctrl       KO         1
Ctrl_KO2               Ctrl       KO         2
Ctrl_KO3               Ctrl       KO         3
```

Everything in the genotype column labeled "WT" is my signal and everything labeled "KO" is my background. So what I essentially want is a way to make the following comparisons where the background (KO) is separated from the signal (WT). I am feeding my model matrix to an R package that will do the rest, I just need to make sure it is set up correctly.

- Drug1WT v. CtrlWT (with Drug1KO and Ctrl1KO as background)
- Drug1_Drug2WT v. CtrlWT (with Drug1_Drug2KO and CtrlKO as background)
- Drug1WT v. Drug1_Drug2WT (with Drug1KO and Drug1_Drug2KO as background)

Additionally, I would also like to compare:

- Drug1WT v. Drug1KO
- Drug1_Drug2WT v. Drug1_Drug2KO
- Ctrl_WT v. Ctrl_KO

I am not sure if these comparisons make sense the way I have my table set up. Here is what I have tried. The sample table is assigned to `dat`.

```
with(dat, model.matrix(~ genotype * condition))
```

This gives me:

```
   (Intercept) conditionDrug1 conditionDrug1_Drug2 genotypeWT
1            1              1                    0          1
2            1              1                    0          1
3            1              1                    0          1
4            1              1                    0          0
5            1              0                    1          1
6            1              0                    1          1
7            1              0                    1          1
8            1              0                    1          0
9            1              0                    1          0
10           1              0                    1          0
11           1              0                    0          1
12           1              0                    0          1
13           1              0                    0          1
14           1              0                    0          0
15           1              0                    0          0
16           1              0                    0          0
   conditionDrug1:genotypeWT conditionDrug1_Drug2:genotypeWT
1                          1                               0
2                          1                               0
3                          1                               0
4                          0                               0
5                          0                               1
6                          0                               1
7                          0                               1
8                          0                               0
9                          0                               0
10                         0                               0
11                         0                               0
12                         0                               0
13                         0                               0
14                         0                               0
15                         0                               0
16                         0                               0
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 1 2 3 3
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$condition
[1] "contr.treatment"

attr(,"contrasts")$genotype
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Questions:

1. Why isn't "KO" included in any of the columns of the design matrix?
2. How does `model.matrix()` choose which coefficients are part of the model? There are combinations I am expected that are missing.
3. Based on what I am trying to achieve, how do I set up contrasts to indicate what I want to compare?

Additionally, any links to tutorials or external sources that could help me out would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take note that the design matrix $X$ has to be [full rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29). That means that its columns cannot be a linear combination of one another. As you do include an intercept (which is correct and should be done in general) your factors (say `genotype`) cannot be fully encoded. If you had a column `genotypeKO` and a column `genotypeWT` where each columns was simply an indicator of the genotype the combination of these two columns would equal your intercept. (The column of `1`'s in the beginning of your design matrix). That's why you do not have a column `KO`. `model.matrix` automatically excludes the first level of the expanded factor you are considering as to prevent linear combinations (read rank-deficient design matrices) to arise. This does not guarantee that the matrix will be full-rank but it makes it more plausible.

Given your design matrix $X$ the easiest way to quickly check its rank in R is to use the [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) like: `qr(X)$rank` to reveal the rank of it. If the rank equates the number of columns (assuming you have more columns than rows) then the matrix is full-rank and the system of equations defined by $X$ has a unique solution. These [online manual](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm) pages from UCLA on variables coding are very enlightening on the matter. This [CV thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105115/) on polynomial contrast encoding (while not directly applicable in your case) should also be a helpful read.

Comment: Using QR decomposition, $X$ is rank 6. When I count columns, I assume I include the intercept column? If so, then my matrix is 16 X 6. Although the rank equals the numbers of columns I have more rows than columns. I am not sure where to go next but I may have a better idea after I read the links in your post.

Comment: From what I have been reading I think my `genotype` column is redundant. Is this correct? If I recode my sample table so that the `condition` column contains the information about being either WT or KO, then I get all the columns I want. But then I am not sure how to specify that the KO samples should be an interaction term.

Comment: Having more rows than columns is fine, actually this is exactly what you want to ensure a unique solution. Interactions terms are specified by `:`. A good succinct reference on Wilkinson Notation can be found [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/wilkinson-notation.html) (Yes, it is for MATLAB but yes, the notation is common.)

Comment: This is an excellent answer to your question @syntonicC. I think you should seriously consider "accepting" it.

Comment: @ Antoni Parrellada Well, I'm still kind of stuck at the moment. This answer points out an error with my setup (which was very helpful) and answers my questions 2 and 3 but I am still not sure how I need to restructure my table to get the contrasts I need (I barely understand the idea of contrast coding at the moment). I have been reading the sources posted trying to understand how this all works. I was intending to come back here when I have a better idea to ask further clarification.