# Can/should I throw out some of my polynomial contrasts & coefficients?

Tags: regression, model-selection, contrasts

I read through [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105115/polynomial-contrasts-for-regression) to help me with a similar model that I'm working on. Only the coefficient for `readcat.L` is deemed significant (per *p*-values):

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  52.7870     0.6339  83.268   <2e-16 ***
readcat.L    14.2587     1.4841   9.607   <2e-16 ***
readcat.Q    -0.9680     1.2679  -0.764    0.446    
readcat.C    -0.1554     1.0062  -0.154    0.877
```

In this case, is it appropriate to choose

$$\hat{y_i} = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_L L_i$$

as your model instead of

$$\hat{y_i} = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_L L_i + \hat{\beta}_Q Q_i + \hat{\beta}_C C_i$$

(where $\hat{\beta}_L$, $\hat{\beta}_Q$, and $\hat{\beta}_C$ are the estimated coefficients for the linear, quadratic, and cubic terms, and $L_i$, $Q_i$, and $C_i$ are the appropriate contrasts for level $i$)?

I'm worried about throwing out the higher-order contrasts, since the values of the lower-order contrasts depend partly on calculating that many at once (right?). Do they have to stick together, or do I keep only the ones with significant coefficients? And if it's okay to get rid of some of them, is it okay to get rid of a lower-order term and keep a higher-order one?