# Is there a fundamental mathematical reason that ordered factors are represented as orthogonal polynomials in linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear-model, ordinal-data, categorical-encoding

At least for R, Chambers/Hastie write in their book "Statistical Models in S" in chapter 2.3.2 "Coding Factors by Contrasts":

> Ordered factors are coded so that individual coefficients represent
> orthogonal polynomials if the levels of the factor were actually
> equally spaced numeric values.

In my opinion, all uncertainty is coded in e.g. "Std. Error". From reference [3] below:

```
set.seed(101)
d <- data.frame(x=sample(1:4,size=30,replace=TRUE))
d$y <- rnorm(30,1+2*d$x,sd=0.01)

summary(lm(y~x,d))
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 0.993167   0.004804   206.7   <2e-16 ***
#   x         2.001782   0.001706  1173.6   <2e-16 ***

summary(lm(y~factor(x),d))
# Coefficients:
#               Estimate  Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#   (Intercept) 2.993959   0.003914   765.0   <2e-16 ***
#   factor(x)2  2.006141   0.006063   330.9   <2e-16 ***
#   factor(x)3  4.003383   0.005006   799.7   <2e-16 ***
#   factor(x)4  6.006763   0.005535  1085.3   <2e-16 ***

summary(lm(y~ordered(x),d))
# Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   5.998031   0.001966 3051.355   <2e-16 ***
# ordered(x).L  4.476056   0.003917 1142.668   <2e-16 ***
# ordered(x).Q -0.001380   0.003931   -0.351    0.728     
# ordered(x).C  0.003363   0.003946    0.852    0.402
```

I would have expected the linear term `ordered(x).L` only (as for numeric values or unordered factors).

The argument that "You don't know, if your asumption of equal spacing was correct, so you add polynomials to simulate non-equal spacing",
points in the direction that "the creation of levels `factor(x)2`, `factor(x)3`, and `factor(x)3`" as well as
"the model where you treat x as numeric" are no longer appropriate models, but is there a **fundmental mathematical reason** for orthogonal polynomials?

PS: It seems that many beginners also do not expect polynomials when they first encounter ordered factors.

---

There are various good references for the treatment of ordered factors in linear regression, e.g.
[1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195246/how-to-handle-ordinal-categorical-variable-as-independent-variable),
[2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381877/whether-to-use-factors-in-r-and-when-ordered-factors),
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735636/interpretation-of-ordered-and-non-ordered-factors-vs-numerical-predictors-in-m),
[4](https://stephendavidgregory.github.io/blog/2017-03-17-ordered-factors/), and
[5](https://data.library.virginia.edu/understanding-ordered-factors-in-a-linear-model/).
But they all don't give a mathematical reason for the choice.

Comment: The fact that these codes were developed as polynomials is irrelevant.  *Orthogonality* is the key condition.  I do not understand your comment about errors-in-variables, because it's a *non sequitur:* it has nothing directly to do with coding choices.

Comment: "Unknown spacing" is a totally different model than "unknown errors."

Comment: @whuber agreed - I deleted this part of the question. But do you have an answer to my question?

Comment: Orthogonal polynomial contrasts help with some kinds of *interpretation.* A proof that they are not mathematically (or statistically) required is provided by the existence of alternative useful codings, such as the one given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/574761/.